# Subclass str to override __eq__ in python to costume set.intersection

Tags: python, string, set, subclass

I wrote a python script in python to create two sets. I was trying to override **eq** in string class, so the equal logic is that if string a is in string b, then a "equal" b. I subclass str class and the two sets contains the new class. 
Then I tried to use set.intersect to get the result. But the result always show 0. My code is like this:

```
# override str class method__eq__
class newString(str):
    def __new__(self, origial):
        self.value = origial
        return str.__new__(self, origial)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return other.value in self.value or self.value in other.value

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)

    def __hash__(self):
        return 1

def get_rows():
    lines = set([])
    for line in file_handler:
        lines.add(newString(line.upper()))
    unique_new_set = lines.intersection(columb)
    intersection_new_set = lines.intersection(columa)

# open file1 and file2 in append model
A = open(mailfile, 'r+U')
B = open(suppfile, 'r+U')
get_rows(intersection, unique, A, AB, CLEAN)

A.close()
B.close()
AB.close()
CLEAN.close()
```

Comment: You have to pass parameter to the `get_rows()` function.

Comment: No, `1` is **not** a valid hash. I already told you, you cannot hope to achieve what you want. Please don't add in additional attempts after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use sets to do this, because you also need to produce the same *hash* values for the two strings. You cannot do that, because you'd have to know *up front* what containment equalities might exist.

From the [`object.__hash__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> Called by built-in function `hash()` and for operations on members of hashed collections including `set`, `frozenset`, and `dict`. `__hash__()` should return an integer. **The only required property is that objects which compare equal have the same hash value**; it is advised to somehow mix together (e.g. using exclusive or) the hash values for the components of the object that also play a part in comparison of objects.

Emphasis mine.

You cannot set the return value of `__hash__` to a constant, because then you map all values to the same hash table slot, removing any and all advantages a set might have over other data structures. Instead, you'll get an endless series of hash collisions for any object you try to add to the set, turning a O(1) lookup into O(N).

Sets are the wrong approach because your equality test does not allow for the data to be partitioned into proper sub-sets. If you have the lines `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`, `quick brown fox` and `lazy dog`, depending on how you build sets you have between 1 and 3 unique values; for sets the values need to be unique in whatever order you add them to a set.

Comment: you mean i have to override __hash__ as well?

Comment: @WayneWang: yes, but you cannot match the requirements; because producing equal hash values for strings that test as equal is not going to be possible.

Comment: I just updated the code. It will have a bad performance? By the way, it seems __hash__ will be a default one if no one provided.

Comment: @WayneWang: you'll have *terrible* performance, because now *all strings* map to the same slot. You may as well not use sets at all.

Comment: ♦:Then how does the set hash string object? Like you said, it hashes all string object to same slot too.

Comment: Should I leave the hash default which inherit from string class? Does it reslove it?

Comment: Once more: *You cannot use sets to solve this problem*. Leaving the has to the default but only overriding `__eq__` doesn't work because you are then breaking the requirements for hashable objects. You cannot create a suitable hash for these objects because your equality test is so very broad.